# Do I still have to use media queries ( to resize/reposition elements ), when I am using bootstrap classes for a responsive design?

Tags: css, media-queries

I am confused between media queries and bootstrap classes. At some point I thought like there'll be no necessity of media queries if we use bootstrap classes but when I used bootstrap for my website, it doesn't look much appealing according as the sizes of the elements are required to increase. For that purpose is media queries only the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Simple answer:*
Yes, **most** of the times Bootstrap classes are enough for both full view, and media-queried mobile views.

*Long answer:*
90% of times, Bootstrap classes are enough for websites (not talking about complexly designed ones). It will be good in both the large and mobile views.

However, most sites using Bootstrap don't just use Bootstrap for CSS. Even Bootstrap's own website doesn't do so, because in the end to make it pixel perfect (due to design requirements, or anything), you do need to add some custom css. A lot of this can be solved if you use Bootstrap SASS, instead of the CDN version to modify variables and then make it according to your wishes. But again, not always.

The reason people don't make entire large websites using Bootstrap is because in the end they will always need some custom CSS. Even if you go through some Bootstrap demo projects on YouTube or such, they do almost always add some form of custom css in the end to give finishing touches.

Bootstrap makes your writing CSS easier, but doesn't replace it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Even bootstrap uses media queries because it's the syntax of CSS, but bootstrap might make it easier for some people. I know for a fact that big companies don't use bootstrap and use pure css or make their own libraries.

Comment: Please read my question before answering.

Comment: Yes there is no other way of making a page responsive other than media queries, there are bootstrap classes that might make it easier for you but some things aren't provided by bootstrap. But obviously if you learn bootstrap you can resize each element without media queries.